# How do I ensure a folder can be renamed in dropbox or google drive?

Tags: python, dropbox, maya

I get an error in python when trying to rename a **folder** using os.rename.

Windows: error 5

This error does not show up at all when running on folders that are not in **dropbox** or **google drive** folder.

The folder is created through my script before attempting to rename it.

The error seems to happen only sometimes.
For example: 
I run os.rename through a script in my ui (that runs in Maya 2015) and it errors.
Sometimes the error will go away after a couple attempts.  However after restarting the UI it comes back.  I feel like there could be something happening in the UI that causes this error, however it only happens when working in folders within dropbox or google drive.

I tried then running the same command on the same folder in eclipse python console right after getting the error, and it works fine there.

Removing dirs was not working until I started running this command on the directory when rmtree encountered an error:

```
os.chmod(directory, stat.S_IWRITE)
```

I try running this on the directory before renaming to see if it will fix the bug

```
os.chmod(directory, stat.S_IRWXU| stat.S_IRWXG| stat.S_IRWXO | stat.S_IWRITE | stat.S_IWUSR)
```

however it does not fix it entirely.

This error only happens when renaming folders, not files.

How do I ensure a folder can be renamed in dropbox or google drive?

Comment: Try running the Python interpreter (or the `cmd` shell you launch it from) with administrative privileges.

Comment: does this happen if you shut down the dropbox or google drive client on your machine?

Comment: You should try to use the dropbox or google drive API instead of just renaming stuff locally. I guess that your issue is linked with the way those services runs under windows, so could be that at some point you are accessing a "non locked" folder and at some other point you are accessing a "locked" folder - and this situation gives you a windows error 5 (that is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, by the way)